# Как получить строку из списка (массива)?

Tags: python, list

Подскажите, как из списка/массива можно сделать альтернативу (т.е убрать цикл):

```
argHelp = ['1', '2', '3']
message = ""
for i in argHelp:
   message = ''.join([message, "Значение %s \n" % str(i)])
print(message)
```

Пробовал таким способом:

```
message = ''.join([message,["Значение {} \n".format(i) for i in argHelp]])
```

Возвращает такую ошибку:

> Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, list found

Comment: ```message = " ".join(argHelp)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно это:

```py
argHelp = ['1', '2', '3']
message = '\n'.join([f'Значение {value}' for value in argHelp])
print(message)
```

Comment: А если message изначально имеет значение? как его сохранить?.
```'\n'.join([message, [f'Значение {str}' for str in argHelp]])```

После добавления message в join ошибка 
```Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, list found```

Comment: @Athreem `message += '\n'.join([f'Значение {str}' for str in argHelp])`

Comment: А без += можно это как то реализовать?
```message = "123"
message = ' '.join([message, "abc"])
print message```
= 123abc, по такому принципу

Comment: @Athreem `message = '123' message += 'abc'`

Comment: Не стоит использовать имена встроенных функций для объявления своих переменных, это я про ```str```

Comment: @Nobody ок, поправил

Answer (score 2):

Можно, конечно, воспользоваться `map()`, но под капотом это тот же неявный цикл:

```
msg = "Значение {}"
res = "\n".join(map(lambda x: msg.format(x), argHelp))
```

поэтому лучше (легче читается) воспользоваться циклом:

```
res = "\n".join([msg.format(x) for x in argHelp])
```

---

результат:

```
In [10]: print(res)
Значение 1
Значение 2
Значение 3
```

Comment: А правильным ли будет написание кода таким способом?
```message = "Передайте один из аргументов для уточнения:%s" % ''.join(f'Значение {i}\n' for i in argHelp)```

Comment: в каком плане? код рабочий, но правильно ли его так использовать?

Comment: @Athreem, пардон, невнимательно посмотрел - да, так тоже можно

Comment: Я не понимаю.А какая разница, правильно или неправильно. Главное чтобы работало. Это лично моё мнение.